# Can't call method from URL when super class is REST_Controller, codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine

I want to run URL from browser and get file content located out of my project, for example: `/home/fessy/file.txt`

I use codeigniter and doctrine.

I have a method:

```
class Api extends REST_Controller {

// ....

public function get_file_content_get(){
   var_dump(array('ftp_path' => $this->uri->segments)); 

       $name      = $this->uri->segment(3);
       $rootPath = $this->uri->segment(4);

       $file = file_get_contents("$rootPath/$name.txt", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

     // $this->_response('success', array('file_contents' => $file));       
}
```

So I generate my URL as:

```
site.com/index.php/api/get_file_content_get/118130/%2Fhome%2Ffessy%2Ffile.txt
```

But I get an error:

```
<xml>
   <status/>
   <error>Unknown method.</error>
</xml>
```

When I change super class from `REST_Controller` to `CI_Controller` I succeeded to call `get_file_content_get` method.

I event can't get `site.com/index.php/api/get_file_content_get/` to call the `index()`

What I'm doing wrong?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:

I need to remove `_get` postfix since Doctrine uses this postfix as GET indicator

Instead:

```
site.com/index.php/api/get_file_content_get/118130/%2Fhome%2Ffessy%2Ffile.txt
```

should be:

```
site.com/index.php/api/get_file_content/118130/%2Fhome%2Ffessy%2Ffile.txt
```